# Pandas groupby transform tweaks

Tags: python, pandas

Below is my pandas code, when we groupby over mask only masked row get the transformed value which is right. But, I wish to fill all the cells in value_transform. Any way to do that? See expected output below

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'dates': ['2023-01-01', '2023-01-02', '2023-01-03', '2023-01-01', '2023-01-02', '2023-01-03', '2023-01-01', '2023-01-02', '2023-01-03'],
    'flag': [True, True, False, False, False, True, True, False, True],
    'value': [10, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 50, 50, 60],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
mask = df['flag'] == True
df['value_transform'] = df[mask].groupby('dates')['value'].transform(lambda x: max(x) - min(x))

ExpecteD:
        dates   flag  value  value_transform
0  2023-01-01   True     10    40.0
1  2023-01-02   True     10     0.0
2  2023-01-03  False     20    10.0
3  2023-01-01  False     30    40.0
4  2023-01-02  False     40     0.0
5  2023-01-03   True     50    10.0
6  2023-01-01   True     50    40.0
7  2023-01-02  False     50     0.0
8  2023-01-03   True     60    10.0
```

Comment: How are you filling the `value_transform` values in the expected output for `flag==False` rows?

Comment: same value as flag=True, value is arrived using flag=True and filled for all dt

Answer (score 1):

IIUC that you want to fill the nans in `value_transform` based on dates, the easiest would be to sort and then `bfill`.

See code below:

```
df.sort_values(['dates', 'flag']).bfill().sort_index()
print(df)
```

Output:

```
        dates   flag  value  value_transform
0  2023-01-01   True     10             40.0
1  2023-01-02   True     10              0.0
2  2023-01-03  False     20             10.0
3  2023-01-01  False     30             40.0
4  2023-01-02  False     40              0.0
5  2023-01-03   True     50             10.0
6  2023-01-01   True     50             40.0
7  2023-01-02  False     50              0.0
8  2023-01-03   True     60             10.0
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can't rely on the ordering of the returned results, you can compute the aggregated view and use `Series.map` to create the new column (note that this is effectively a `reduction` + `{merge,join}`:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'dates': ['2023-01-01', '2023-01-02', '2023-01-03', '2023-01-01', '2023-01-02', '2023-01-03', '2023-01-01', '2023-01-02', '2023-01-03'],
    'flag': [True, True, False, False, False, True, True, False, True],
    'value': [10, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 50, 50, 60],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

mask = df['flag'] == True
aggregations = (
    df.loc[mask].groupby('dates')['value']
    .agg(['max', 'min']) # this will be faster than passing a lambda
    .eval('max - min')
)

df['value_transform'] = df['dates'].map(aggregations)

print(df)
#         dates   flag  value  value_transform
# 0  2023-01-01   True     10               40
# 1  2023-01-02   True     10                0
# 2  2023-01-03  False     20               10
# 3  2023-01-01  False     30               40
# 4  2023-01-02  False     40                0
# 5  2023-01-03   True     50               10
# 6  2023-01-01   True     50               40
# 7  2023-01-02  False     50                0
# 8  2023-01-03   True     60               10
```

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.__version__
'1.5.3'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'dates': ['2023-01-01', '2023-01-02', '2023-01-03', '2023-01-01', '2023-01-02', '2023-01-03', '2023-01-01', '2023-01-02', '2023-01-03'],
    'flag': [True, True, False, False, False, True, True, False, True],
    'value': [10, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 50, 50, 60],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Calculate max - min values for each 'dates' group where 'flag' is True
mask = df['flag'] == True
grouped = df[mask].groupby('dates')['value'].agg(lambda x: max(x) - min(x)).reset_index()
grouped.columns = ['dates', 'value_transform']

# Merge the calculated values back into the original DataFrame for 'flag' == True rows
df = df.merge(grouped, on='dates', how='left')

# Fill NaN values in 'value_transform' column with 0
df['value_transform'] = df['value_transform'].fillna(0)

print(df)

dates   flag  value  value_transform
0  2023-01-01   True     10               40
1  2023-01-02   True     10                0
2  2023-01-03  False     20               10
3  2023-01-01  False     30               40
4  2023-01-02  False     40                0
5  2023-01-03   True     50               10
6  2023-01-01   True     50               40
7  2023-01-02  False     50                0
8  2023-01-03   True     60               10
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77232583/edit), not here in comments (*** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Run a where clause on the value column using the flag column, do a groupby, compute the min and max on the grouped object and assign the result back to the original dataframe:

```py
grouped = df.value.where(df.flag).groupby(df.dates)
df.assign(value_transform = grouped.transform('max') - grouped.transform('min'))
        dates   flag  value  value_transform
0  2023-01-01   True     10             40.0
1  2023-01-02   True     10              0.0
2  2023-01-03  False     20             10.0
3  2023-01-01  False     30             40.0
4  2023-01-02  False     40              0.0
5  2023-01-03   True     50             10.0
6  2023-01-01   True     50             40.0
7  2023-01-02  False     50              0.0
8  2023-01-03   True     60             10.0
```